# Can I use an if statement as condition in another if statement in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

Can I do that? I´ve searched for an answer, but I couldn´t found any. What I want to do is this:

```
if(a==5)
{
   printf("25");
}

if((if(a==5))==TRUE)
{
    printf("\n30");
}
```

Is this permissible in C?

Comment: Show an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why are you trying to do this? it seems you are over-complicating something that should not be that complicated.

Comment: well, your logic needs more thinking, you can just merge those 2 "IF", since they're get executed when say a=5, right?! or if a!= 5, means first one doesn't get executed, right? then first IF is false, so second one doesn't get executed neither. so combine them in one IF. plus, although,  there is no shame in asking questions, at least study a bit, before presenting what you've got(rick&morthy).good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
if(a==5)
{
   printf("25");
}

if((if(a==5))==TRUE)
{
    printf("\n30");
}
```

can be rewritten this way with keeping the same logic

```
int condition;

if( ( condition = a == 5 ) )
{
   printf("25");
}

if( condition )
{
    printf("\n30");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use an if statement as condition in another if statement in C?

No, you can´t do that, it isn´t syntactically correct. You would get this or a similar error for the inner `if` test, if you would attempt to compile code that has any occurrence of that in its source code:

> error: expected expression before 'if'

But it is already redundant since you can proof several expressions inside just one `if` statement´s condition test by using the logic operators `&&`(AND) and `||`(OR):

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

if(a == 5 && b == 10)     // If a is 5 AND b is 10. - true
{
    /* some code */
}
```

or

```
int a = 6;
int b = 10;

if(a == 5 || b == 10)     // If a is 5 OR b is 10. - true
{
    /* some code */
}
```

---

Given your example:

```
if(a==5)
{
   printf("25");
}

if((if(a==5))==TRUE)
{
    printf("\n30");
}
```

The inner `if` statement inside the condition of the outer `if` statement - `if((if(a==5)) == TRUE)` isn´t permissible but also redundant, because an `if` statement proofs on its own whether the condition or a sub-expression is true or not.

Thus, `if((if(a==5)) == TRUE)`, `if((a==5) == TRUE)` and `if(a==5)` would be all equivalent, if a `if` condition test inside the condition of another were permissible and the `if` statement shall somehow be evaluated to `1`.

So even in this surreal case, the code in the example would be equivalent to:

```
if(a==5)
{
   printf("25");
   printf("\n30");
}
```

Comment: I'm... pretty sure `if((if(a==5))==TRUE)` is not valid C.

Comment: @Quentin You are completely right. I didn´t proof that. I only proofed `if((a==5) == TRUE)` - dumb mistake. I edited my question massively. Thank you very much.